# HttpStatus with ResponseEntity and pdf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc controller which produces an "application/pdf" to download a generated pdf. I want to return always the pdf and also return different HTTP codes depending on certain conditions.

I tried to return a ResponseEntity<> object but always response is 200 with the PDF (always the pdf is generated, but I need different status responses).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/obtain/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getPdfFile(HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" +"file.pdf" +"\"");
    String error = getPDF(response, request);
    logger.debug("PDF error : " + StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(error,"null") );
    return new ResponseEntity<>("",HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

**Note : Inside getPDF method, is just the code which generates the pdf and write it to the response.getOutputStream()**.

The idea behing is that I want to return ALWAYS the pdf in the outputstream, but different result codes (200, 500, etc). Event when I return 500, I want to return a PDF. Is it possible?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, how you are returning the error in getPDF(), please share code of that

Comment: It does not matter how the error is generated, since always is returning 200, even if I use directly : return new ResponseEntity<>(Http Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

Comment: If your getPDF() is returning some string no matter error is there or not then it will be always not null which always give 200. So can you check with that and let me know

Comment: I changed the code in my initial post because maybe it was confusing, since if I return directly 500 in the responseEntity, the browser is returning me the pdf and a 200.

Comment: Hello moisesbelda, go through my answer and let me know your thoughts on it

Comment: Have you tried with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about this, but I think the method is returning whatever is in the `HttpServletResponse`, rather that the object you are returning.

I think you should experiment with `HttpServletResponse.getWriter().write(responseEntity.getBody())` and `HttpServletResponse.setHttpStatus(responseEntity.getHttpStatus())`, or just the equivalent hard-coded values...

Also, are you seeing the errors and the 200 status alongside each other? If so, try parameterizing the entity as a String - whatever Throwable you put in there should still work fine.

Please let me know if you try that and it doesn't work so I can edit or remove this answer - I haven't actually tried this yet, but interested to find out why that code is not working.

Comment: The response is 200 and a pdf (since in getPDF a pdf is written to the outputstream). The error string is not displayed and I have the same result if I directly put 500, I mean, forcing the 500 always).